# Objects seems to be deleted if not assigned to object variable in PySide

Tags: python, qt4, pyside

I'm trying to use QStandardItemModel to represent a hierarchy of data, but when I'm adding QStandardItems to the model, I have to assign them in object member variables, or the objects seems to be deleted.

For example

```
self.tree_model = QStandardItemModel()
self.tree_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Category'])
self.out_insertions = QStandardItem("Insertions")
self.tree_model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(self.out_insertions)
```

Works as expected (an "Insertion" row is inserted under the column "Category"). But if I remove the self.out_insertion assignment, like:

```
self.tree_model = QStandardItemModel()
self.tree_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Category'])
self.tree_model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(QStandardItem("Insertions"))
```

It doesn't work (an empty row is shown).

I'm using Qt 4.6.3 and PySide 0.4.1.
Can someone explain me why this happens?

Thanks in advance

~Aki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object get garbage collected since no more (Python) references to it exist.

This behavior is described in the '[things to be aware of](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#garbage-collection)' in the PyQt documentation.

Most of these problems (in PyQt land) can be avoided by correct `parenting` (which makes Qt take ownership instead of PyQt).

Comment: It means that QStandardItemModel doesn't keep internal references to items?!? This sounds pretty odd...

Comment: Well, I thought about that issue anyway, probably it's a matter of deallocation/destruction... That explains why using local variables instead of object variables would not solve. Anyway what I just find odd is that objects shall be referenced inside StandardItemModel and thus not destroyed... But why?

Comment: it is explained quite well in the "things to be aware of" link above. basically its a side effect of following the pyqt method of doing bindings rather than a more pythonic view - which hopefully pyside will implement in a future release. In the meantime - just make sure the thing you create is associated with a more persistent higher level entity. (like a parent window)

Comment: Looks like "things to be aware of" is gone: getting 404. Does anybody has an alternative link where I can read about that?